# What Theia image to use inside Che?

Tags: eclipse-che, theia

https://github.com/eclipse/che, upcomming che 7 could use Theia as the default editor.
Which docker image and which tag is to be used ?

Answer (score 0):

It is **eclipse/che-theia**, which is located [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/eclipse/che-theia/).
The version of this image consists of two parts: 
`[THEIA_VERSION]-[CHE_VERSION]`
- first one - the version of Theia inside the image
- second one - the Che version itself (ex. `eclipse/che-theia:0.3.10-nightly`, `eclipse/che-theia:0.3.10-6.7.0`, [etc](https://hub.docker.com/r/eclipse/che-theia/tags/))